# Abstract factory add to dictionary from config

Tags: c#, configuration, dictionary, abstract-factory

Hi have my factory code like this. Instead of storing in dictionary directly i want to store these values in app.config file. As i have shown below.

```
public class HandlerFactory
    {
        private Dictionary<string, IHandler> _handlers = new Dictionary<string,IHandler>();
        public HandlerFactory()
        {
            _handlers.Add("AMOUNT", new AmountValidator());
            _handlers.Add("FLOW", new FlowValidator());
        }
        public IHandler Create(string key)
        {
            IHandler result;
            _handlers.TryGetValue(key, out result);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I would to move these settings to my config file as shown below.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <configuration>
        <configSections>
            <section name="Indentifiers" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection"/>
        </configSections>
        <Indentifiers>
            <add key="AMOUNT" value="AmountValidator" />
            <add key="FLOW" value="FlowValidator" />
        </Indentifiers>
    </configuration>
```

I was doing something like this, but i didn't succeed. Not sure how to add to dictionary

```
NameValueCollection settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Indentifiers") as NameValueCollection;
                if (settings != null)
                {
                    foreach (string key in settings.AllKeys)
                    {
                        _handlers.Add(key.ToString(), settings[key].ToString()); <-- how to handle here
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance` should be useful here.

Comment: Hi Chaos, i am calling createInstance in my main class and not the Factory class. In my main class i am doing something like this '                IHandler validator = handle.Create(arInfo[0].ToString());
                IHandler handler = (IHandler)Activator.CreateInstance("Validation", validator.ToString()).Unwrap();'  But i don't understand how to convert the value of key to type IHandler. ie. from 'AmountValidator' to 'AmountValidator of type Ihandler' in my factory class. Did you  get me? Can you please advise?

Comment: I think you are not understanding the purpose of a factory. Think about the definition for a second. Would a car factory produce a blueprint of a car or an actual car?

Answer (score 0):

As ChaosPandion points out, the CreateInstance method should be useful.
Assuming both of your handler types implements IHandler, and they are located in the running assembly,

```
_handler.Add(key.ToString(), Activator.CreateInstance(null, settings[key].ToString()));
```

should do the trick!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx
First argument is the name of the assembly, and null defaults to the executing assembly.

Comment: Hi olagjo, I don't want to create instance on my factory class, instead i am doing it in my main class. as shown'   HandlerFactorys handle = new HandlerFactorys();

            if (handle.isValid(arInfo[0].ToString()))
            {
                IHandler validator = handle.Create(arInfo[0].ToString());
                IHandler handler = (IHandler)Activator.CreateInstance("Validation", validator.ToString()).Unwrap();
                handler.Validate(Message);
            }' But the thing is how to convert string to Type Ihandler when i am reading from config? Did you get my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IHandler
{
    void Handle();
}

public sealed class HandlerFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _map = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    public HandlerFactory()
    {
        var handlers = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Handlers");
        if (handlers == null)
            throw new ConfigurationException("Handlers section was not found.");
        foreach (var key in handlers.AllKeys)
        {
            var typeName = handlers[key] ?? string.Empty;
            // the type name must be qualified enough to be 
            // found in the current context.
            var type = Type.GetType(typeName, false, true);
            if (type == null)
                throw new ConfigurationException("The type '" + typeName + "' could not be found.");
            if (!typeof(IHandler).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                throw new ConfigurationException("The type '" + typeName + "' does not implement IHandler.");
            _map.Add(key.Trim().ToLower(), type);
        }
    }

    // Allowing your factory to construct the value 
    // means you don't have to write construction code in a million places.
    // Your current implementation is a glorified dictionary
    public IHandler Create(string key)
    {
        key = (key ?? string.Empty).Trim().ToLower();
        if (key.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot be null or empty or white space.", "key");
        Type type;
        if (!_map.TryGetValue(key, out type))
            throw new ArgumentException("No IHandler type maps to '" + key + "'.", "key");
        return (IHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chaos, i am getting error at 'The type 'Validation.BuyValidator' does not implement IHandler, even though it implements IHandler.' My config file is like <Handlers>
  <add key="Buy" value="Validation.BuyValidator" />
  <add key="Sell" value="Validation.SellValidator" />
 </Handlers>

Comment: @bayyinah - If you look closely at my original code you'll notice the if statement that checks to see if the type implements IHandler needed to be negated.